# How to create a variable from summarize command in Stata?

Tags: variables, stata, summarize

```
summarize X , detail  

gen un_p5 = di r(p5) 
gen un_p10 = di r(p10) 
gen un_p25 = di r(p25)
gen un_p50 = di r(p50) 
gen un_p75 = di r(p75) 
gen un_p90 = di r(p90) 
gen un_p95 = di r(p95) 
gen un_p99 = di r(p99)
```

I want to `summarize, detail` another variable Y in order to `ttest` whether the percentiles of both variables (X, Y) are equal

```
summarize Y, detail 

gen c_p5 = di r(p5) 
gen c_p10 = di r(p10) 
gen c_p25 = di r(p25)
gen c_p50 = di r(p50) 
gen c_p75 = di r(p75) 
gen c_p90 = di r(p90) 
gen c_p95 = di r(p95) 
gen c_p99 = di r(p99)
```

I get this error when using `gen` command to create a variable

```
di not found 
r(111) ;
```

I want to `ttest`
`un_p5 = c_p5`

```
  un_p10 = c_p10
```

for each percentile-.

Comment: Each pair of quantiles is just one data point, so the _t_ test intended sounds meaningless: neither "variable" is a variable.  Even if you bundle all those quantiles together, they are not mutually independent and using 8 of them is arbitrary. To compare distributions, start with a quantile-quantile plot. These are statistical issues to be raised with local advisors and/or a statistical forum.

Comment: You have comments and an answer. Whether they are or are not what you want, you shouldn't ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Just omit `di`: it is here irrelevant as well as illegal. The pattern you are seeking is

```
gen un_p5 = r(p5)
```

Note that you need `summarize, detail` for this to be useful. (With `summarize` alone, the above statement is legal, but will just store numeric missing in every observation.)

But why you are putting 8 constants in 8 variables is unclear. Those constants will be repeated in every observation.  Why not use scalars instead, or a vector? What do you want to do here?

Comment: The questions in the last paragraph are addressed in an edit. My comment on the question makes some statistical remarks.